# Let enemies blink when hit

Tags: actionscript-3

I would like to know how can I go about with an approach, that lets the enemies blink after they are hit with a shot/particle?

Is it better to pre-render colored enemies into an array for a better performance or is it just okay coloring them during gameplay?

For example, you can use the `colorMatrixFilter-` or `colorTransform-` methods for accomplishing this. Pre-rendering it (mentioned before) and storing the colored enemies inside of an array is an option also.

I ask because I'm not sure how those mentioned methods influence gameplay, especially for action games.

Which method is *usually* faster / *the accepted norm*? Are there any approaches I should avoid that will impact the gameplay?

Comment: I think he meant doing the pre-rendering on game load - so there would be one asset that's rendered to two versions. I think this is tactic fairly common in actionscript because displaying pre-rendered vector graphics is faster than drawing vector graphics each frame.

Comment: @CiscoIPPhone My bad, I don't know enough about specific AS3 dev, which is why I posted as a comment. Sorry @drpelz if that was confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are doing blitting with `copyPixels()` then you should definitely pre-render it inside flash when the program launches or the level is loading**

Instead of changing the enemies color when hit, you should probably make a hit animation for the enemies and just play that animation when hit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm gonna use TweenLite because it's fast and calculate it during gameplay. I can't pre-render it because animations consist about 400 small images stored in a tilesheet and each of it needs to be rotated about 360 degrees if I pre-render the stuff. That would result in a super-array consisting of about 400 * 360 pre-rendered images (144000). That's way tooooooooo much! So I'll stick with TweenLite which is fast and easy to use (I hope so).:)

Comment: @drpelz So your sprites are images from a spritesheet? Rotating them using TweenLite won't look pretty though, as the sprite will get pixelated.

Comment: No, no. They are already rotated by the framework I use. What I need is a fast coloring method. I need this when I shoot and hit an enemy the enemy shall flash for a short period of time. Currently I can't do that inside of the framework I use so TweenLite is a real alternative (well I hope so:)).